# Command line utilities in macOS only accept options at the first args

Tags: command-line, macos

The command line utilities in Linux accept for example:

```
tail file.log -fn0
```

But the utils in macOS don't, the options must be first arg:

```
tail -fn0 file.log
```

Is it possible to change this?

Comment: This is not related to zsh at all, it's up to the commands you call  to process their arguments.

Comment: The shell, be it Bash or zsh or something else entirely, only passes the stuff it's given to the utility for processung. It doesn't know what an "option" is, or where one can and can't be placed.

Comment: Historically all options were supposed to be placed before the files they affected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the Zsh in MACOS doesn't accept, the options must be first arg:

This is very likely because macOS is a [BSD-derivative](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/articles/explaining-bsd/) which means that the common utilities (like `grep`, `tail`...) are the of BSD-variant, and not the GNU versions which are used on Linux

This means that there are some slight (and sometimes huge) variations in functionality, usage...

---

> Is it possible to change this?

Yes, you can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install the GNU versions of the tools

Homebrew will not replace the default utilities *(by default)*, but put them in your `PATH` and for most you can access them by prepending `g` (for GNU) to the tool name, in your case that would be `gtail`

For the relevant info and commands, see this [Apple.SE answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88812/411451)